# concatenate two arrays into additional dimension python

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

I have 2 arrays shape of each `(50,50,3)`
when I do concatenation .... I need the new dimension to be :

```
(2 , 50 , 50,3)
```

where 2 is for 2 images
I tried:

`np.concatenate((cat01 , cat02 ) , axis = 0)`

outputs `(100 , 50 , 3)`

And

`np.concatenate((cat01 , cat02 ) , axis = 1)`

outputs `(50 , 100 , 3)`

So How Could I add Another dimension to the array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or:

```
np.array((cat01, cat02))
```

a bit simpler than

```
np.concatenate((cat01[None], cat02[None), 0)
```

and roughly as fast.

```
>>> cat01 = np.ones((50, 50, 3))
>>> cat02 = np.zeros((50, 50, 3))
>>> 
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=100000)
>>> 
>>> timeit("np.concatenate((cat01[None], cat02[None]), 0)", **kwds)
0.7162981643341482
>>> timeit("np.array((cat01, cat02))", **kwds)
0.7192633128724992
>>> timeit("np.stack((cat01, cat02))", **kwds)
1.1847702045924962
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
np.stack((cat01, cat02))
```

Then the shape is `(2, 50, 50, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat01G = cat01[np.newaxis , :,:,:]
```

just add np.newaxis this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

While `stack` is convenient, it is a good idea to understand how to use `concatenate` directly:

```
np.concatenate((cat01[None,...] , cat02[None,...] ) , axis = 0)
```

In other words - adjust the dimensions of each of the input arrays.  Using `None` or `np.newaxis` should become something you use routinely in `numpy`.  Also learn to do the same thing with `reshape`.

Also try:

```
np.expand_dims(cat01, axis=0)
```